# For a project using Rails with Java backend, where to construct ElasticSearch query, front end or back end?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am writing a project using Ruby on Rails with Java as backend. I noticed that ElasticSearch has an open-source [Ruby client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-dsl) where it could construct JSON query, and it also has [Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).

In this case, should I use the Ruby client (creating query in the front end) or the Java API client (creating query in the back end)? What would be the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: What do you mean that you have a "Rails project" with "Java as the backend"?

Comment: @chrylis Because the functionality of the website is complicated most of the backend code is written in Java. Rails is served as a place that simply manages the front-end components.

Comment: I am assuming that your Rails app is calling the api which are written in Java. And I also I am assuming that there are some models(database tables in Rails), and there are some tables in your Java API. Now you want to integrate elastic search into your java tables or rails tables?

Comment: @gates Java API has direct access to the database not Rails. Currently, all the query has to go through the Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Java API has direct access to the database not Rails. Currently, all the query has to go through the Java API.

Do you still have doubt?

If your rails app is used as client, then let be it. And let your Java/backend handle the backend explicitly. Just pass the query params from your rails app and construct, execute and return query results from your Java app.

Comment: It is the current practice. Still not sure if it is the best way to go. Generating query with the ElasticSearch Ruby package seems to be very flexible. Currently, Java app needs to contain a lot of translation code that converts the query params using ElasticSearch Java API.

Comment: I understand that, but that's the best practice keeping your client and server different, else you will create a mess in future with such distributed code. Imagine, you come up with an android app in future and you need to query, you will have to create an api in rails for search and java for others, thus end up creating 2 endpoints...nay...